# Create posts without login from frontend

Tags: posts, wp-insert-post

I am new to WordPress development ,I am using `wp_insert_post()` to create posts from front end, This function works fine when I have already logged in but I need to implement this without any login .

can you please guide me the exact way how this can be achieved .

```
$post = array(
 'post_title'   => "Tshirt-custom-order-".$last_inserted,
 'post_content' => "oio",
 'post_status'  => "publish",
 'post_excerpt' => "uuu",
 'post_name'    => "order_custom_".$last_inserted, //name/slug
 'post_type'    => "product",
 'post_author' =>6
 );
 //Create product/post:
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
//$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Everyone would be able to publish spams on your blog.

Comment: basically I am having customizing Tshirst website so there I need to create a post prodcut type which they have specified.

Comment: You could store these data in custom fields. User input should not be trusted.

Comment: ok But is there is any way to implement this with wp_insert_post

Answer (score 2):

You should not allow anonymous users to publish anything on your website without authentication. If you need to store custom data that is specified by users, you should use the custom fields instead.

In your case, [`add_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) comes in handy. After creating a post using `wp_insert_post()`, pass its ID to `add_post_meta()` and add custom fields to that specific post:

```
$id = wp_insert_post( $args );
if ( $id ) {
    add_post_meta( $id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
}
```

You should also sanitize the user input before inserting it into the database. You can use [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) for this very purpose.

Comment: This does'nt worked becuase post is not created . is there is any to give author id static in all the post that we have created ?.

Comment: Hmm you can use another approach. If the users need to register to buy a product, you can store these data on their user account, instead of creating a post.

Comment: Actually my client require this way to order and then the created post in the cart .then the checkout later on

Answer (score 2):

**Non Plugins:**

Look at wp insert post args:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

You should create html input for some of those $args. When post submitted (if isset post) you can do :

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()){
$newid = wp_insert_post($args); 
if ($newid){ 
// add_post_meta here if  your post type have 
//some success notification 
} else { 
//some failed notification 
}
}
```

**Using Plugins:**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

looks easier way